ADFS: SSL handshake failes
I'm running ADFS on Windows Server 2022 Std and used
 Set-AdfsSslCertificate -Thumbprint 'd0ab1c1b7ba1ba76bef717086bb3aaacf4783899'

via powershell. It was accepted, read rights for the private key were created, adfs was stopped and restarted.
When checking that the cert is used, I tried openssl:
openssl s_client -crlf -connect localhost:443

Result:
CONNECTED(000001C8)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 176 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1718272457
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---

What could I try next?
Kind regards
Alex
